# Jquery: can I make this Ajax box align to the left and right depending on where the link is?

Tags: jquery, html, css

new to jquery here and I've come up with an Ajax box to appear under a link. It works correctly for links on the left side of the page but when a link is on the right, the box aligns incorrectly with the page. I'm using absolute positioning for the box ATM which is why it aligns as it does.

Is there a way to have it align correctly to the right for links on the left-side and then to the left for links on the right-side of the page. Insights really appreciated! Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/5hUbG

Comment: what is the desired result? The box seems to appear under the link, is this not the desired position?

Comment: when you click the link floated to the right the box opens out to the right (causing a scroll bar to appear), that's the page edge and i'd like it to expand out to the left keeping the page width undisturbed.

Comment: Oh I see that now, sorry for my confusion. I suggest finding the width of the link, and the width of the generated object, and adjusting by those widths

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a rough method of doing it:

http://jsfiddle.net/PdCHZ/12/

[**edit**]: I updated it to use the tooltip's width from the CSS:
[**edit number 2:**] if you add this:

```
 $('<div/>',{html:"", id:'tooltip'}).css({visibility:"hidden"}).prependTo( 'body' );
```

at the beginning of `$(document).ready(function () {` then the oWidth code will automatically get the width from the CSS.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a.link").click(function () {
        var $link = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/echo/html/',
            data: {
                html:'these would be the returned data form the <strong>AJAX</strong> call..'
            },
            success: function (response) {
                var pos = $link.position();

                // this just gts the number of pixels from the left of the screen
                // that the element is.
                var offset = $link.offset();

                //set oWidth to 300 unless you want to create a hidden tooltip
                //before this, so that it can read the width from that.
                var oWidth = $("#tooltip").width(); 

                // modifier gets set to -oWidth if the link is less than
                // pixels from the right of the screen (this makes it pop up 
                // to the left of the link instead of to the right)
                // (if the element is more than 300 from the right, then it gets set to 10, like you had it originally)
                var modifier = (offset.left>$(document).width()-oWidth)?-oWidth:10;

                   $('#tooltip').remove();

                   // all i've done here is changed your "10" to "oWidth"
                   // so that it either turns into -300 or +10 depending on
                   // where the link clicked on is on the screen.
                   $('<div/>',{html:response, id:'tooltip'}).css({left:pos.left+modifier+'px', top:pos.top+10+'px'}).prependTo( 'body' );

            }
        });
    });
});
```

You could replace "300" with something like `$("#tooltip").width()` so that you wouldn't have to update it, but you probably get the idea.

The magic happens here:

```
var modifier = (offset.left>$(document).width()-oWidth)?-oWidth:10;
```

If you're not familiar, this is just a shorthand if statement equivalent to this:

```
if(offset.left>$(document).width()-oWidth){
    var modifier = -oWidth;
} else {
    var modifier = 10;
}
```

Then you just add modifier to the pos.left and you have your positioning.

Comment: thanks you so much for the help, its going to take me a little bit to work thru that and see exactly what you're doing here. Would you know why if you click the right link first the ajax box doesn't expand properly, however, if you click it a second time it works and works everytime after that?

Comment: because oWidth is reading it's value from `$("#tooltip")`, it can't find a value until after tooltip has been created. you can just manually assign `var oWidth = 300;` instead of `var oWidth = $("#tooltip").width();` to solve this. or create a hidden tooltip so that it can read it straight from your html

Comment: @trying_hal9000 I commented the code to make it easier for you.

Comment: @trying_hal9000 I also added that if you put `$('<div/>',{html:"", id:'tooltip'}).css({visibility:"hidden"}).prependTo( 'body' );` at the beginning of the document.ready area, then that will also fix the problem, it will allow $("#tooltip").width() to find the width from the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

may I suggest something like:

```
if ($link.parent().hasClass('right'))
                $('#tooltip').css({left:+pos.left + $link.outerWidth() - $('#tooltip').outerWidth() + 'px'});
```

just added to the end of your success function?